# Don't use static cast for arithmetic conversions (cpp-core-guidelines)

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines

msvc's code analyzer for the cpp core guidelines tells me

> Warning   C26472  Don't use a `static_cast` for arithmetic conversions. Use
> brace initialization, `gsl::narrow_cast` or `gsl::narrow`
> (type.1).

for this snippet

```
static_cast<IntType>(static_cast<unsigned long long>(hexValue(digit)) << (digitIdx * 4));
```

Why shouldn't I use static_cast here?

Also, with brace init this would look like this

```
IntType{unsigned long long{hexValue(digit)} << (digitIdx * 4)};
```

which doesn't look any better imo. This looks more like a function style cast than anything else.

I cannot use gsl and I think `gsl::narrow` is a wrapper around `static_cast` itself, so is this purely a readability issue here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so is this purely a readability issue here?

Nope. Brace initialization prohibits narrowing conversions, and will cause a diagnostic. The guideline's purpose is to help protect code from unintended narrowing. A `static_cast` will allow a narrowing conversion through silently.

You seem to be dealing in integers, so short of using an extended integer type that is larger than `unsigned long long`, you'll probably not hit any narrowing.

But the guideline is there for the general case, and it's better to write code consistently, even when there is no actual risk.

Comment: `IntType` is a template so there will almost always be narrowing in the left `static_cast` won't there (i.e. when `IntType != unsigned long long)`?

Comment: @Timo - Ah, you are correct. I confess I got fixated on the inner static_cast. Yes you are correct, this will usually cause narrowing. `gsl::narrow_cast` exists for this cases. It makes the potential for narrowing stand out (which is why the diagnostic is silenced). If you can't use it then you only have `static_cast` available. Disabling the warning locally, and a comment will probably do if you can't pull in `gsl`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26472?view=vs-2019

> - `gsl::narrow` ensures lossless conversion and throws `gsl::narrowing_error` if it's not possible.
> - `gsl::narrow_cast` clearly states that conversion can lose data and it is acceptable.

`static_cast` doesn't perform these checks, so it is safer to explicitly state your intentions.

Answer (score 2):

> Warning C26472: Don't use a static_cast for arithmetic conversions. Use brace initialization, `gsl::narrow_cast` or `gsl::narrow` (type.1).

The advice "Don't use static_cast for arithmetic types" is a strict version of Avoid casts and prefer named casts (said in type.1).

My advice is that, in order to keep type safety strictly, `static_cast` should be not used for arithmetic conversions. However, in many occasions, the chance of unsafe type cast is very low or type safety can be well ensured by algorithms and programs, `static_cast` could be used for arithmetic conversions.

---

More thinking about type safety of arithmetic types is giving as following:

Brace initialization is an ideal type-safe strategy as it prohibited narrowing conversions. For `gsl::narrow` and `gsl::narrow_cast`, there are no similar narrow conversion functions in C++ Standard Library at present.

> - `gsl::narrow` ensures lossless conversion and throws gsl::narrowing_error if it's not possible.
> - `gsl::narrow_cast` clearly states that conversion can lose data and it's acceptable.

According the document of GSL, `gsl::narrow_cast` is a named cast that is identical to a `static_cast`.
Thus, it would still cause unsafe narrow conversion as it does not check the value it is converting (same as `static_cast`). For example,

```
std::uint8_t c1 = gsl::narrow_cast<std::uint8_t>(1000.5);// same as using static_cast
std::uint8_t c2 = gsl::narrow_cast<std::uint8_t>(-1.5); // same as using static_cast
```

The above code can be run successfully, while the narrow conversion is still unsafe.
If you do not want to use GSL and do not care too much about performance, arithmetic conversions could also be implemented by writing a simpler type-safe `numeric_cast` function as giving in the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
void error(const std::string& errormessage){
    std::cerr << errormessage;
    throw std::runtime_error(errormessage);
}

template <typename Target, typename Source>
constexpr Target numeric_cast(Source&& src){    
    if (typeid(Target) != typeid(bool) &&
        (src < std::numeric_limits<Target>::lowest() ||
         src > std::numeric_limits<Target>::max())  )
        error("Unsafe numerical cast.\n");
    return static_cast<Target>(std::forward<Source>(src));
}

int main() {    
    //1. Numerical promotion
    float f1{ 1.1f };   double dd1{ f1 }; //Suggested!
    double d1{ numeric_cast<double>(f1) }; //Ok
    
    //2. Numerical narrowing
    double dd2{ 1.1 }; float f2 = numeric_cast<float>(dd2); //OK 
    std::size_t uu2{ 10 }; std::uint8_t u2 = numeric_cast<std::uint8_t>(uu2);  //OK 

    //3. Numerical truncating
    double d3{ 1.5 }; std::uint8_t u3 = numeric_cast<std::uint8_t>(d3);  //OK 

    // Errors detecked
    //double d4{ -1.5 }; std::uint8_t u4 = numeric_cast<std::uint8_t>(d4); //error detecked
    //double dd4{ 1000 }; std::uint8_t uu4 = numeric_cast<std::uint8_t>(dd4); //error detecked   
}
```

The `numeric_cast` function could be used for numerical promotion, numerical narrowing and numerical truncating simultaneously.  It can also find the errors of unreasonable arithmetic conversions by check the value it is converting and the limits of converting target.

Of course, to keep typy-safety, the performance of `numeric_cast` is relatively lower when compared with other arithmetic conversions without value check.