# Arithmetic overflow warning when trying to allocate memory using new

Tags: c++

This is my minimal reproducible example.

```
struct Cell
{
};

void initializeCells(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, unsigned int size, Cell* outcell)
{
    outcell = new Cell[(width / size) * (height / size)];
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Cell* cells = nullptr;
    initializeCells(1200, 600, 10, cells);
}
```

I am getting a warning in line `outcell = new Cell[(width / size) * (height / size)];` saying

`Warning    C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow (io.2).`

How can I cast the value to a wider type like the warning is suggesting? Also something else that's weird is that the warning sometimes disappears for a few minutes and comes back again and is inconsistent. I am using visual studio 2019 and the inbuilt compiler.

Comment: Thanks to all the answers and my issue is solved. However, when I use `size_t` and hover my mouse over it, it says `unsigned long long`. Isn't that a complete overkill to store an `int` of 1200 and 600?

Comment: You aren't really *storing* anything for very long. And the conversion will *potentially* be done *anyway* when the `new[]` operator is called.

Comment: Also, by changing the parameters to `size_t` you'll likely just be using 3 64-bit registers rather than 3 32-bit registers; and there's nothing wrong with passing `unsigned int` types - they'll be *silently* promoted to `size_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a `size_t` from an `unsigned int`, then multiplies the `size_t` with an `unsigned int`.

```
outcell = new Cell[size_t{ width / size } * (height / size)];
```

Depending on the use of `width`, `height` and `size` you might instead consider making these a `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

The size of an array is `std​::​size_­t` per [[dcl.array]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.array#1).  Knowing that, you can make that the type of your function parameters like

```
void initializeCells(std​::​size_­t width, std​::​size_­t height, std​::​size_­t size, Cell* outcell)
{
    outcell = new Cell[(width / size) * (height / size)];
}
```

Alternatively, you can cast one of the operands to a `std​::​size_­t` to force the expression to use that as its result type like

```
outcell = new Cell[(static_cast<std::size_t>(width) / size) * (height / size)];
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is caused by the fact that the operand of `new[]` is of `size_t` type, which is apparently a 64-bit unsigned integer on your platform (but the `unsigned int` arguments are 32-bits).

A quick way to silence the warning is to cast the results of the divisions to `size_t` type:

```cpp
    outcell = new Cell[static_cast<size_t>(width / size) * static_cast<size_t>(height / size)];
```

However, a (perhaps) better way would be to change the argument types of `initializeCells` to `size_t`:

```cpp
void initializeCells(size_t width, size_t height, size_t size, Cell* outcell)
{
    outcell = new Cell[(width / size) * (height / size)];
}
```

Comment: On MSVC this would trigger the code analysis warning that you are using a C style cast (`size_t(...)`).

Comment: @WernerHenze Actually, it doesn't - it's a functional-style cast. But you're right: I have edited the code sample to use a better (C++) cast.

Comment: `static_cast` is not necessary. MSVC also emits code analysis warnings when using `static_cast` for arithmetic covnersion (as done here) and suggest using a brace initialization as in `size_t{...}`.

Comment: @WernerHenze I beg to differ. I compiled the posted code snippets with VS-2019 (64-bit build), with full warnings enabled, and there is no warning given. And why is brace initialization any different (really) from my *original* function-style cast (which actually *is* a constructor)?

Comment: These are not regular compiler warnings. These are code analysis warnings (when enabling code analysis with "MS Native Recommended Rules").

Comment: @WernerHenze I know. Code analysis also emits no warning.

Comment: I just tested. You are right, MSVC 16.8.3 does not emit such a warning in that case. But it exists, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62410916/dont-use-static-cast-for-arithmetic-conversions-cpp-core-guidelines.

Comment: @WernerHenze That's a very different kettle of fish! The conversion in your linked post is a **narrowing** one.

Answer (score 0):

This warning occurs because if `width/size` ends up being the max value of `unsigned int` and `height/size` is too, the multiplication would overflow. This is relevant because allocating an array always takes an integer with the size of the system's address size (8 bytes in your case, same size as the type `size_t` has). By simply casting your values to `size_t`, you can mitigate this warning:

```cpp
#include <cstddef> // this header contains the size_t type

// ...

outcell = new Cell[static_cast<size_t>(width / size) * static_cast<size_t>(height / size)];
```

Comment: You are using two C style casts. This is not modern C++ (compare [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es48-avoid-casts)).

Answer (score 0):

`width`, `height` and `size` are `int` which is 4 bytes in size. When multiplied, by default it is cased to a `int` type. 
But the `new[]` operator looks something like this,

```cpp
void* operator new[](size_t size) { ... }
```

This means that the `new[]` operator takes the size in bytes as a `size_t` value (which is basically an unsigned 64 bit integer).

To resolve this, you can either static cast the variables before multiplying it like this,

```cpp
outcell = new Cell[(static_cast<size_t>(width) / static_cast<size_t>(size)) * (static_cast<size_t>(height) / static_cast<size_t>(size))];
```

Or you can alter the function signature like this,

```cpp
// Note that size_t is unsigned long long under the hood.
void initializeCells(size_t width, size_t height, size_t size, Cell* outcell)
```

Comment: _"This might be an issue"_ It isn't. _"as the size of it is 0 bytes."_ It isn't.